# Can I split to tweet data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, split, nlp, tweets

```
df1 = pd.read_json('1.json')

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12]) 
print(df)
```

I have Dataframe data and I want to split URL with under code.

```
def remove_url(txt):
 return " ".join(re.sub("([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", "", str(txt)).split())'''
```

and I call data that hasn't got to URL under code.

```
all_tweets_no_urls = [remove_url(tweets.content) for tweet in tweets] #tweets.content
all_tweets_no_urls[:10]
```

when this code run in python I have this

```
['0 coronavirues coronavirus coronarovirus Ko1 Korona da isinler in 10 deprem korkusu bitti imdi de deli gibi corona100 inliler daha seni tanmadndan corona virs1000 akrabalk ba corona virs bundan daha az t 9995 60 yandaki korona hastas 155 gn sonra you9996 pastdelusion Yiaaa bakarm bakarm uan pek k9997 handelendi Maske takmyorumZaten salya smk9998 3 doktor arkadam 2 defa corona oldunCovid9999 feyzasays BulutGulcuN Kim diyor yokmu diye Name content Length 1072101 dtype object']
```

In this answer all of the tweets show only one table. But I want to answer like this.

```
['Mardin Bykehir Belediyesi Kltr Turizm ve Sosyal ler Daire Bakanlna bal Mesleki Eitim Merkezinde MARM',
 'SosyalUyumveGenlikKatlm projesi ile genlik merkezimizde eitim ve faaliyetlere katlm salayan ensar ve muha',
 'Ahi Evren Gs Kalp ve Damar Cerrahisi Eitim ve Aratrma Hastanesi alan Fatih Aksuolu yakaland Covid19',
 'le Jandarma Komutanlmz ile Sahil Gvenlik Karakol Komutanlmz Gzelaml sahilinde Covid19 tedbirleri',
 'Mardin Bykehir Belediyesi Kltr Turizm ve Sosyal ler Daire Bakanlna bal Mesleki Eitim Merkezinde MARM']
```

How can I see tweets split each other tweets like shown ???

```
['tweet1', 'tweet2'.....]
```

Comment: Please, indent and format your code properly. It is not readable like it is now.